# NArgMax plotting partially wrong solution

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization

In the following MWE, `NArgMax` finds the correct argmax (`br1`) as a function of the parameter `p2` for most values of `p2`, but not close to zero. Instead, a vertical line is plotted. `NArgMax` gives a constant value to `br1` for `p2` close to 0.

To confirm the wrongness of the solution, in the 3D plot, the objective function to maximize is smooth and its max at different `p2` reaches the origin. Thus the argmax and the maximized value should reach the origin, which can be proved theoretically as well.

No breakpoints of the `Piecewise` part of the objective function are where `NArgMax` kinks into the wrong solution. `Trace` shows a correct derivation until the last step. After that a value of `p1` is selected that makes the objective zero, but a positive objective is attainable at small positive `p1`, which should be the max.

```
Clear[d1, q1, pi1, p1, p2, γ, br1, pi1opt, plot1, plot3]
$Assumptions = 
  0 < q1 < q2 && 0 <= p1 < p2 && 
   0 <= p2 < q2 && (p2 - p1)*q1 >= p1*(q2 - q1) && p1 < q1 && 
   0 < γ < 1;
cdf[v_] = 
  Piecewise[{{0, v < 0}, {v^2/γ, 
         0 <= v < γ}, {1 - (1 - v)^2/(1 - γ), γ <= 
  v <= 1}, {1, v > 1}}];
d1[p1_, p2_, q1_, q2_] = Max[0, cdf[(p2 - p1)/(q2 - q1)] - cdf[p1/q1]];
pi1[p1_, p2_, q1_, q2_] = p1*d1[p1, p2, q1, q2];
γ = 0.1; q1 = 1; q2 = 1.2;
br1[p2_] = br1[p2_?NumericQ] := NArgMax[pi1[p1, p2, q1, q2], p1]
{br1[0.001], br1[0.01], br1[0.1]}
pi1opt[p2_] = 
 pi1opt[p2_?NumericQ] := NMaxValue[pi1[p1, p2, q1, q2], p1]
plot1 = Plot3D[{pi1[p1, p2, q1, q2]}, {p1, 0, q1}, {p2, 0, q2}, 
RegionFunction -> Function[{p1, p2, z}, p1 < p2], 
AxesLabel -> {Subscript[P, 1], Subscript[P, 2]}, 
PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]];
plot3 = ParametricPlot3D[{br1[p2], p2, pi1opt[p2]}, {p2, 0, q2}, 
AxesLabel -> {Subscript[P, 1], Subscript[P, 2], Subscript[π, 
 1]}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Orange, Dashed}];
Show[plot1, plot3]
Plot[br1[p2], {p2, 0, q2}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

How to make `NArgMax` find the correct maximum at all points?

Using `ArgMax` instead of `NArgMax` with the same numerical parameters, the `Plot` is empty and the `Plot3D` is missing the dotted line denoting the maximum.

Comment: Your code doesn't run - I get `Plot3D::plln: Limiting value c1 in {p1,c1,1} is not a machine-sized real number.`

Comment: Corrected it, thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

Adding constraints to rule out the wrong answer of `NArgMax` fixes the problem. Now `NArgMax` finds the correct solution. Code below. The cause of the problem is still unknown.

```
Clear[d1, d2, q1, q2, pi1, pi2, p1br, p2br, df, c1, c2, p1, p2, \
α, β, γ, br1, br2, pi1opt, pi2opt, plot1, plot2, \
plot3, plot4, plot5, refl4, constraints]
constraints = 
  0 < q1 < q2 && 0 <= c1 <= c2 && c1 <= p1 < p2 && 
   c2 <= p2 < β*q2 && (p2 - p1)*q1 >= p1*(q2 - q1) && 
   p1 < q1*β && 0 <= α < γ < β;
$Assumptions = constraints;
cdf[v_] = 
  Piecewise[{{0, 
 v < α}, {(v - α)^2/((β - α)*(γ \
- α)), α <= 
      v < γ}, {1 - (β - 
          v)^2/((β - α)*(β - γ)), γ \
<= v <= β}, {1, v > β}}];
d1[p1_, p2_, q1_, q2_] = Max[0, cdf[(p2 - p1)/(q2 - q1)] - cdf[p1/q1]];
d2[p1_, p2_, q1_, q2_] = 1 - cdf[Max[p2/q2, (p2 - p1)/(q2 - q1)]];
pi1[p1_, p2_, q1_, q2_] = (p1 - c1)*d1[p1, p2, q1, q2];
pi2[p1_, p2_, q1_, q2_] = (p2 - c2)*d2[p1, p2, q1, q2];
(*Parameter values specified numerically. Use 1., 0., etc to force \
floating point numbers instead of symbolic. *)
α = 0.; β \
= 1.; γ = 0.8; q1 = 1.; q2 = 1.2; c1 = 0.; c2 = 0.;
br1[p2_] = 
 br1[p2_?NumericQ] := NArgMax[{pi1[p1, p2, q1, q2], constraints}, p1]
br2[p1_] = 
 br2[p1_?NumericQ] := NArgMax[{pi2[p1, p2, q1, q2], constraints}, p2]
pi1opt[p2_] = 
 pi1opt[p2_?NumericQ] := 
  NMaxValue[{pi1[p1, p2, q1, q2], constraints}, p1]
pi2opt[p1_] = 
 pi2opt[p1_?NumericQ] := 
  NMaxValue[{pi2[p1, p2, q1, q2], constraints}, p2]
(*{br1[0.01],pi1opt[0.01]}*)(*Test whether br1 exists at low p1. *)

plot1 = Plot3D[{pi1[p1, p2, q1, q2], pi2[p1, p2, q1, q2]}, {p1, 
    c1, β*q1}, {p2, c2, β*q2}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{p1, p2, z}, p1 < p2], 
   AxesLabel -> {Subscript[P, 1], Subscript[P, 2]}, 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]];
plot2 = ParametricPlot3D[{p1, br2[p1], pi2opt[p1]}, {p1, 
    c1, β*q1}
   , AxesLabel -> {Subscript[P, 1], Subscript[P, 2], Subscript[π, 
     2]}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue, Dashed}];
plot3 = ParametricPlot3D[{br1[p2], p2, pi1opt[p2]}, {p2, 
  c2, β*q2}, 
  AxesLabel -> {Subscript[P, 1], Subscript[P, 2], Subscript[π, 
  1]}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Orange, Dashed}];
Show[plot1, plot2, plot3]
plot4 = Plot[br1[p2], {p2, c2, β*q2}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}];
plot5 = Plot[br2[p1], {p1, c1, β*q1}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
   AxesLabel -> {Subscript[P, 1], Subscript[P, 2]}, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}];
refl4 = plot4 /. 
   line_Line :> {Orange, 
     GeometricTransformation[line, ReflectionTransform[{-1, 1}]]};
Show[plot5, refl4, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 300]
```